# An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.-Mulesoft Error

Tags: java, oracle, mule, mule-component, mulesoft

Getting the following error **"An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out "** in Mulesoft while trying to implement database pooling with the configuration shown in image below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/US7PM.png)

Please let me know if anything need to be changed in the pooling configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure to consume the output of the database queries and operations in the flows. If they are not consumed, the connections will not be returned to the pool, and eventually the pool can run out of available connections. For example, a  after each operation will iterate and consume the results.

Comment: I'm using that database configuration to a stored procedure which has output parameter.
is that not consuming the output?
if so please explain  what do you mean by consuming the output of database query.

Comment: The Database connector operations have an output which is a result set. It can be consumed by iterating over the payload with a foreach.